# When can you use a const int as the size of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, constant-expression

Why am I able to use a locally declared `const int` as the size of an array declaration but am not allowed to do the same with a `const int` passed as an argument?

For example, in the below code why do I get compiler errors only on line 2?

```
void f1(const int dim){
  int nums[dim];  // line 2: errors
}

void f2(){
  const int dim = 5;
  int nums[dim];  // ok
}
```

Comment: wt is your compilter ?

Comment: @ANjaNA VS2013. i.e. Version 18

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Array size should be known at compile time.

`const int` with local variables may do not work neither if the value is not known at compile time as:

```
void f2(){
  const int dim = bar();
  int nums[dim];  // error
}
```

In Both case, `const int` tells that the value doesn't change, not that is it known at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

In `f2` the constant `dim` is known at compile time, in `f1` it's not.

And since C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) the dimensions of an array must be known at compile time.

The use of `const` for function arguments is more of a hint to the compiler that the function will not modify the argument, allowing the compiler to for example make optimizations based on that information.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of the `const` keyword is wrong. `const` implies that within a certain contextual scope the variable will not change, not that the variable is determined at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Array size should be known at compile time.**
2. `const` mean the value doesn't change.

So, this is about value of 'dim` at compile time.

In first case, it is unknown. compiler don't know the value of `dim` at compile time. It depends on the value passed to the function.

```
void f1(const int dim){
  int nums[dim];  // line 2: errors
}
```

In this case, `dim` value is known at compile time, so no issues.

```
void f2(){
  const int dim = 5;
  int nums[dim];  // ok
}
```

You can use a feature in c++ 11 for this.

define your function as `constexpr`.

```
constexpr int getDim(......)
{
    .......
    .......
    return dim;
}
```

then call `getDim` inside `f1`.

```
void f1(){
  int dim = getDim(...); //// computed at compile time
  int nums[dim];
}
```

Note that, use of `constexpr` depend on your application. Further refer [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-compile-time-processing-with-constexpr.html).

Comment: `int dim = getDim(...); //// computed at compile time` should be `constexpr int dim = getDim(...); //// computed at compile time`

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11 though you can use [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) which would do what you expect. The `constexpr` says compiler that apart the variable is `const` its value can be evaluated at compile time.