# c++ variable size stack array in function that get const

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

I'm learning now C++ I'm reading the book Effective C++ (Scott Meyers).
In the book, there is an item about const variables, and I try to work with them.
I notice something very interesting that I what to know if it bug in C++:
(I'm working with C++98 standard)

```
void Test(const int i)
{
    int arr[i] = {0};
    
    for (int j = 0; i > j; ++j)
    {
        arr[j] = i;
    }
}
```

This function will compile and work exactly as I want (create int array on the stack with the size of 'i'. When I remove the 'const' from 'i' it won't compile.
I try this on gcc and clang.

Edit:
link to [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/4fz3ad)

Comment: I don't think that's standard, it might be a GCC/CLANG extension. In C++, array sizes have to be known at compile time.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476227/using-const-int-as-array-size) says they get an error for the same thing.

Comment: Some compilers support the C Variable Length Arrays in C++. It is not a good idea to use it though. It interacts badly with other C++ features like templates and object creation and destruction.

Comment: @ZanLynx But if the compiler supports VLA it should work without `const` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To catch this kind of mistake in the future the compiler flag you want for both g++ and clang++ is `-pedantic`. And always remember to specify your language standard or you don't know what you'll get.

```
$ g++ -std=c++98 -pedantic c++-vla.cpp -o c++-vla
c++-vla.cpp: In function ‘void f(size_t)’:
c++-vla.cpp:3:30: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘g’ [-Wvla]
    3 | void f(const size_t x) { int g[x]; }
      |                              ^

$ clang++ -std=c++98 -pedantic c++-vla.cpp -o c++-vla
c++-vla.cpp:3:31: warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]
void f(const size_t x) { int g[x]; }
                              ^
1 warning generated.
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `const` in your function signature is ignored by the compiler. So the following two are equivalent:

```
Test(const int i) {}
Test(int i) {}
```

Secondly, this isn't valid C++ regardless of whether it compiles or not:

```
int arr[i] = {0};
```

It isn't valid because `i` is not a compile time constant i.e., the value of `i` has to be known at the time of compilation.

Try on [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8TaPe8)

Comment: I think `const` in the function signature prevents assigning the variable inside the function.

Comment: Yes, but to the compiler it doesn't make a difference whether it is `const` or not (for value types).

Comment: It doesn't make a difference when deciding whether to allow it to be used as an array size, but it makes a difference for other things.

Comment: I try it on compiler Compiler Explorer - [link](https://godbolt.org/z/4fz3ad)
This compiled and work

Comment: That's because of GCC's own extensions that make it work. Compile with `-pedantic` and then see what happens. Also, read this post for a bigger answer to why GCC allows this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334435/variable-length-array-vla-in-c-compilers

Comment: To the **caller** those two versions of `Test` are the same thing. Top-level `const` is ignored for function overloading. **Inside** the function they are not the same thing: in the first version, `i` cannot be modified; in the second, it can.